# NGINX and Lua scripting: conditional use in content_by_lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm trying to create a conditional content_by_lua script, where the content should be set by lua only under a turthy condition.

example:

#### nginx.conf

```
location / {
        content_by_lua_file  /nginx/lua/nginx.lua;

        root   /nginx/www;
        index  index.html;

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff|ttf)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }
    }
```

#### nginx.lua

```
if condition then
    ngx.header["Content-type"] = "text/html"
    ngx.say('<H1>Hello World.</H1>');
    ngx.exit(0)
else
    -- serve the original content (index.html)
end
```

the problem is - lua scripting under nginx doesnt support 2 content directive within the same route, is there a workaround I can do?

with the current usage when the condition false I expect the index.html to be shown but receive a blank page instead

Comment: For those of us not overly familiar with nginx what *exactly* about what you have here isn't working?

Comment: @EtanReisner edited my question

Comment: How are you trying to serve the condition in the `-- serve the original content` block?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `ngx.exec` call which does an internal call.

**nginx.conf**

```
location / {
    content_by_lua_file  /nginx/lua/nginx.lua;

    root   /nginx/www;
    index  index.html;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff|ttf)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
}

location /default_index {
    root   /nginx/www;
    index  index.html;
}
```

**nginx.lua**

```
if condition then
    ngx.header["Content-type"] = "text/html"
    ngx.say('<H1>Hello World.</H1>');
    ngx.exit(0)
else
    -- serve the original content (index.html)
    ngx.exec("/default_index", ngx.var.args)
end
```